# retrieve bounding box of a geodjango multipolygon object

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango

How can I get the bounding box of a MultiPolygon object in geodjango? Can't find anything in the API http://geodjango.org/docs/geos.html ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`extent`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#extent) property.

It returns a 4-tuple comprising the lower left and upper right coordinates, respectively.

You can also use the [`envelope`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.Envelope) property if you want a `Polygon` object representation of the bounding box.