# Get Bounding Box from Django PolygonField

Tags: django, postgis

I am trying to get the bounding box for a `PolygonField` in a Django model. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793240/retrieve-bounding-box-of-a-geodjango-multipolygon-object) that you can use `extent` but when running the below as per the `extent` documentation:

```
qs = newJob.objects.filter(pk=1).aggregate(Extent('loc'))
print(qs['loc__extent'])
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 86, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function st_extent(geography) does
> not exist LINE 1: SELECT ST_Extent("app_newjob"."loc") AS
> "loc__ext...
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

My model (simplified) looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class newJob(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    loc = models.PolygonField()
```

And in my test:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Extent

newJob.objects.create(
    name="test",
    desc="test",
    loc="SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0.9063720703125029 52.32023207609735, 0.8239746093749998 52.10819209746323, 1.170043945312496 52.14191683166823, 1.170043945312496 52.31351619974807, 0.9063720703125029 52.32023207609735))"
)

qs = newJob.objects.filter(pk=1).aggregate(Extent('loc'))
print(qs['loc__extent'])
```

I'm running a PostGIS database on the back.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be an option to get the extent directly from PostGIS?, e.g. `SELECT ST_Extent('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0.9063 52.3202, 0.823 52.1081, 1.1700 52.1419, 1.1700 52.3135, 0.9063 52.3202))')`

Comment: I guess so. However, unless I've completely misunderstood the documentation, Django should be handling all of that for me. I should just be able to call `Extent` on my PolygonField and be done with it.

Comment: I honestly know nothing about Django, but I would argue that bringing the whole polygon to the application and from there deriving its extent is slower than letting the database do that for you. Specially if you deal with large / many polygons. Using ST_Extent you bring the software to the data, and using `Extent` in Django you bring the data to the software ;) cheers

Comment: @JimJones, using aggregates and Extent as shown in the question should generate SQL that does the aggregation in the DB. Django will not pull the data over and do an aggregation in Python/software. 

I cannot explain the error. All I can say is that I have just used a similar Extent aggregate on Django 2.0 with PostGIS without any issues.

Comment: @KlausCPH if that's the case it is a pretty good alternative to the "real thing". Thanks for pointing it out. Cheers!

Comment: @JimJones, I'm very impressed with the ORM in Django. Been writing Django backend code to two years full-time now, and still haven't had to write a single line of SQL yet :-) I do have to read it to be able to optimize the ORM-code though. 
And btw, here's the SQL generated for my use of the Extent:
`SELECT ST_Extent("app_area"."poly") AS "poly__extent" FROM "app_area" WHERE "app_area"."supplier_id" = 1`